# Adding Int array values in the set of type short

Tags: java, integer, set, hashset, short

```
public class Solution {
    public Set<Short> setx = new HashSet<>();

    public void AddAll(int[] numbers) {
        for (int number : numbers) {
            setx.addAll((short) number);
        }
    }
}
```

This is throwing this error:

```
Solution.java:8: error: incompatible types: short cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Short>
setx.addAll((short) number);
^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

How should I change the code for this to run?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Collections addAll()` method here.

```
Collections.addAll(setx,(short) number);
```